# How can I recognize whether it is a class or interface in java by seeing the name?

Tags: java

I like to know how can I recognize whether it is a class or interface by seeing the name ..
For example all class name starts with capital letters..
method name starts with small name..
Is there any specific way to recognize it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some people make all their interfaces start with an I. Like `IPopup`, or `IController`. I personally hate this.

I was taught that an interface should be an adjective, a class should be a noun. For example: Class: `Controller`, Interface: `Controllable`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. Some people use a naming convention that distinguishes, but many people do *not*. For example, *Sun does not*.

Answer (score 2):

The Java language makes no specific requirements on naming conventions. Indeed, you can define a method `CamelCase()` or a `class lowercase`. There are some [recommended conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html), but the language won't stop you from breaking them - and they don't give a distinction between classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the convention that the development teams are using. However, as a practice in java(including JDK) interface names are not different from classnames in terms of convention.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a naming convention. Some people follow IMap and Map; Map and MapImpl; Map and HashMap and etc. 
However, if the name is an adjective (like Serializable or Comparable) it is hard to imagine it would be a class.
You can also use java.lang.Class.forName("MyInterface").isInterface() for that purpose.